# Can't Upload products via CSV file

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, file-upload

I am trying to import products from import/export profile in magento 1.9. I am trying to import a csv file but the csv file is not being imported and the following error is being displayed.

Does anyone knows why is it persisting.[image]

The data is accurate and I have checked any error related to the products entry in the csv file. Can anyone explain how and why this error is being generated.

Comment: Please write the error of your screenshot in your post, so others can find it from google.